# numpy cov (covariance) function, what exactly does it compute?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I assume `numpy.cov(X)` computes the sample covariance matrix as:

```
1/(N-1) * Sum (x_i - m)(x_i - m)^T (where m is the mean)
```

I.e  sum of outer products. But nowhere in the documentation does it actually say this, it just says "Estimate a covariance matrix".

Can anyone confirm whether this is what it does internally? (I know I can change the constant out the front with the `bias` parameter.)

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/ma/extras.py#L1257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see looking at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1947), in the simplest case with no masks, and `N` variables with `M` samples each, it returns the `(N, N)` covariance matrix calculated as:

```
(x-m) * (x-m).T.conj() / (N - 1)
```

Where the `*` represents the matrix product<sup>[1]</sup>

Implemented roughly as:

```
X -= X.mean(axis=0)
N = X.shape[1]

fact = float(N - 1)

return dot(X, X.T.conj()) / fact
```

If you want to review the source, [look here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1947) instead of the link from Mr E unless you're interested in masked arrays.  As you mentioned, [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) isn't great.

<sup>[1]</sup> which in this case is effectively (but not exactly) the outer product because `(x-m)` has `N` column vectors of length `M` and thus `(x-m).T` is as many row vectors.  The end result is the sum of all the outer products.  The same `*` will give the inner (scalar) product if the order is reversed.  But, technically these are both just standard matrix multiplications and the true outer product is only the product of a column vector onto a row vector.

Comment: Right, and this is equivalent to my sum of outer products?

Comment: @Andrew Yes it is, and I've tried to make it clearer in my answer for you and others.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is what `numpy.cov` computes.  FWIW, I have compared the output of `numpy.cov` to explicitly iterating over the samples (like in the pseudocode you provided) to compare performance and the difference in the resulting output arrays is what one would expect due to floating point precision.