# Is there any better way to calculate the covariance of two lists than this?

Tags: python, math, covariance

I have two lists, one of which consists of x coordinates and the other consists of y coordinates.

```
x_coordinates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_coordinates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For example, `point 1` is `(1,1)`

I want to calculate the covariance of the two lists and I have programmed a code, but I think it's somewhat unnecessarily long and messy.
I know that I can calculate this just using math.cov, but I wonder if it is possible to program this neatly, maybe with map and lambda functions.

The formula is like this:

```
(x1 - average_x)*(y1 - average_y) + ... + (xn - average_x)*(yn - average_y) / (the number of the items in one of the lists)
```

The code:

```
import math

x_coordinates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y_coordinates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
covariance_temp_sum = 0

x_mean = math.fsum(x_coordinates) / len(x_coordinates)
y_mean = math.fsum(y_coordinates) / len(y_coordinates)

for n in range(len(x_coordinates)):
    covariance_temp_sum += (x_coordinates[n] - x_mean) * (y_coordinates[n] - y_mean)

covariance = covariance_temp_sum / len(x_coordinates)
```

Comment: Is numpy allowed?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701094/how-is-covariance-implemented-internally-in-numpy). Maybe it will help.

Comment: Yes, you can express this more neatly - for one thing you can iterate over both lists at once and not use an index variable which you don't really need. Better, you can express this as a list comprehension which has the advantage of also being faster.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I meant numpy.cov, not math.cov. I'm studying python structures and functions, so I hope to learn how to calculate this without using fancy modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use external modules, you can approach it like this:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mean_x = sum(x) / len(x)
mean_y = sum(y) / len(y)

sum((a - mean_x) * (b - mean_y) for (a,b) in zip(x,y)) / len(x)
```

Output: `2`

Answer (score 2):

You can do these things elegantly using comprehensions, zip, and multiple variable assignment:

```
sum((x - x_mean)*(y - y_mean) for x, y in zip(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)) / len(x_coordinates)
```