# How to find COVARIANCE for two lists with floating point numbers?

Tags: python

I need to find covariance for data in two lists of same length. Both contain floating point numbers.

I cannot use for loop, because indices only work with integers and slices, that is the error I am getting with for i in zip(list, list)
..

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "indices only work with integers and slices"? You have a list of FP numbers, you can use indices to address elements in the list. The type of element is not relevant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any better way to calculate the covariance of two lists than this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670055/is-there-any-better-way-to-calculate-the-covariance-of-two-lists-than-this)