# Simple implementation of NumPy cov (covariance) function

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I was trying to implement the `numpy.cov()` function as given here:  [numpy cov (covariance) function, what exactly does it compute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062804/numpy-cov-covariance-function-what-exactly-does-it-compute), but I am getting some bizarre results. Please correct me:

```
import numpy as np  
def my_covar(X):  
    X -= X.mean(axis=0)  
    N = X.shape[1]  
    return np.dot(X, X.T.conj())/float(N-1)

X = np.asarray([[1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0],[3.0,3.0]])

## Run NumPy's implementation
print np.cov(X)
"""  
NumPy's output:
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
"""

## Run my implementation
print my_covar(X)  
"""  
My output:  
[[ 2.  0.  -2.]  
 [ 0.  0.  0.]  
 [ -2.  0.  2.]]  
"""
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: What errors and results and what do you expect?

Comment: For those who forgot about statistics classes and wonder what was the problem here: the correct result is `np.cov(x)` and the users result is incorrect.

Comment: This question should be **reopened**.  It contains the code, the desired result and reference material.  Just a shame I don't know this subject enough to answer myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both your function and `np.cov` (by default) assume that the rows of `X` correspond to *variables*, and the columns correspond to *observations*.

When you center `X` by subtracting the mean, you need to compute the mean over *observations*, i.e. the columns of `X` rather than the rows:

```
X -= X.mean(axis=1)[:, None]
```